# Compatibilty with AMD processor

Tags: 2010

I have access to AMD 8-core processor with 16GB RAM. Will I face any compatibility issues if I use AMD instead of Intel for SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Microsoft fully supports AMD and Intel x86-64 processors that meet the minimum system requirements.